# How to display elements of a JSON array?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I've created a small table with json column and I want to display all the names in the table like this:

```
 id_test |                                                                              test                                                                               
---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       1 | {"clients":{"nbr":"2","info":[{"nom":"med","genre":"male","age":"25"},{"nom":"aicha","genre":"female","age":"24"}]}}
       3 | {"clients":{"nbr":"3","info":[{"nom":"yns","genre":"male","age":"23"},{"nom":"oussama","genre":"male","age":"24"},{"nom":"sara","genre":"female","age":"27"}]}}
       2 | {"clients":{"nbr":"1","info":{"nom":"kenza","genre":"female","age":"26"}}}
```

Desired output:

```
  name   
---------
 med
 aicha
 yns
 oussama
 sara
 kenza
```

Also i want to list the number of gender each genre

Desired output:

```
 genre  | count 
--------+-------
 female |     3
 male   |     3
```

Comment: Please provide sample data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) [not as screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of the [JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html).

First query:

```sql
SELECT
    json_array_elements(CASE
        WHEN json_typeof(test->'clients'->'info') = 'array' THEN test->'clients'->'info'
        ELSE json_build_array(test->'clients'->'info')
    END)->>'nom' AS name
FROM my_table;
```

Second query:

```sql
SELECT
    json_array_elements(CASE
        WHEN json_typeof(test->'clients'->'info') = 'array' THEN test->'clients'->'info'
        ELSE json_build_array(test->'clients'->'info')
    END)->>'genre' AS genre,
    count(*)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: Thank u for your response but i have this error :ERROR:  ERREUR:  ne peut pas appeler json_array_elements sur un type non tableau


SQL state: 22023

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand french. But I think this is (sort of) the correct error: `cannot call json_array_elements on a non-array`, which is because I missed the last example input entry (this is why you really **should use text instead of images** - because people then can copy-paste example data). The updated queries work with your examples.

Comment: thank you very much I tested the requests you have to change and it worked